# Maintaining a persistent copy of a Java collection on disk

Tags: java

In my app I have a Java collection (specifically a `ConcurrentHashMap<String,Queue<MyObjectThatImplementsSerializable>>`)

Is there any library out there that will give me a disk backed implementation that will be persisted/restored across application restarts, and will dynamically write/remove objects as I add/remove objects from the map?

I want to preserve some state that is stored in such an object as transparently as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommend a fast & scalable persistent  Map  - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536953/recommend-a-fast-scalable-persistent-map-java)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Hazelcast and providing a [disk persister](http://www.hazelcast.com/documentation.jsp#MapPersistence).

Answer (score 1):

you also have disk-backed-map http://code.google.com/p/disk-backed-map/